# Create recovery disk for win8

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, recovery-disk, recovery-partition

I have a HP ENVY dv6 which came with Windows 8. I deleted Win8 from the computer when I was installing ubuntu 12.04. I didn't delete the recovery partition though. Now I want to go back and get the computer the same as it was for the first time. However, the recovery system does not work and I'm not able to restore Win8. Ubuntu works fine.

I'd like to know whether it is possible to create a bootable disk from the recovery partition (which is 32 GB) or not. If not, what should I do?

Comment: it is not the same, as I completely delete windows from the computer

Comment: Their Windows doesn't boot/work either.  The answer as pointed out in that question is boot to the Recovery Partition, no OS required. Have you attempted that yet?  When you say the Recovery System "doesn't work", what doesn't work about it?  How far do you get?

Comment: It is not about windows not working. Windows does not exist in my laptop anymore after installing ubuntu.The only thing i have now is the original recovery partition, but it does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" in what way? How far do you get? If you get an error, what's the exact error you're getting, and at what point are you getting that error?  Have you called HP to enquire about acquiring a recovery disk set?

Comment: I didn't call HP yet. The error come up after I press F11. Apparently the boot system does not recognize the recovery partition

Comment: Sounds like the recovery partition is damaged then, so (IMO) you're best/only option is to call HP.

Comment: yep, I think so :(

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

1. Start computer.
2. Immediately hold down the Ctrl key. At the same time start clicking the F11 key (top row of keyboard.) This may let the computer boot into the recovery partition.
3. If it boots into the recovery partition you should be bale to click "Restore," and then "Confirm" to restore your computer. Click "Finish" when prompted to do so, and then select "Yes" to reboot.
4. You may see a different prompt to click "Next" and click "OK" to reboot depending on your specific computer model

[Full instructions from HP](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=5296055&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03483233-6%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

Comment: Hi. That is the usual way to go through. It does not work for me. When I press F11 an error message from windows come up. It says it cannot find required files (despite the entire partition is there!)

Comment: since u r not running windows anymore i guess u can't make a bootable disk from recovery partition. u can try to install a windows version alongside ubuntu and then create a bootable disk from the recovery partition. The bootable disk hence created can be used to restore ur pc to the time u purchased it.

Comment: I cannot install win8 because I get an error as (apparently) the installer needs some drivers that are not in the installation disk.

Comment: There is some problem with the disk u r using to install windows. It might not be bootable. Try using some other disk.

Comment: It is bootable, as I can get started with the installing process. However, after few steps an error msg come up.

Comment: Try to boot using any other installation disks and check if it works perfectly or not.